# Can quickbread be prepared in advance?

Tags: quickbread

I would like muffins, banana bread, and the like for breakfast. Could I prepare a quickbread ahead of time such that my husband would just have to pop it in the oven when he gets up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some muffins with very thick batter can be held for up to several days before being baked, but these are the exception, rather than the rule.

However, quick breads, whether sliced loaves, whole loaves, or muffins, freeze *extremely* well.  Muffins are especially easy to reheat in the microwave or a toaster oven, and can be an ideal way to have quick breads prepared in advance.

Another way (which offers fresh, hotly baked breads) that I like I do before busy holidays that will have muffins or cornbread on the menu, is to prepare the dry mix, and the wet mix, and stick them (separately) into the refrigerator.   Then, it is only a matter of combining them, putting them in the pan, and baking.